# Column search fails after modifying cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have the following code (snippet attached):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
        Exact matches overview
    </title>
     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script/api_recs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script/site_filter.js"></script>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.css"/>
    
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/sorting/natural.js"></script>
    
    
     
        <style type="text/css">
            tfoot {
                display: table-header-group;
            }
    
            html {
                width: 58%;
            }
    
            .red_background {
                background-color: #ffe4e9 !important;
            }
    
            .red_bold_font {
                font-weight: bolder;
                color: red;
            }
    
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <img id="loader" src="/static/img/loader_animation_large.gif" 
     style="
      width:36px; 
      height:36px; 
      display: none;
      position:absolute; 
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      margin-top:-18px;
      margin-left:-18px;"/>
     <p><a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a> | <a href="/accounts/profile/">Home</a></p>
        
        <div id="title">
            <b style="font-size:200%">Exact matches overview<br></b>
        </div>
    
        <table id='matches_table-id' class="display" cellspacing="0" style="float: left;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                
                    <th>Date</th>
                
                    <th>Customer name</th>
                
                    <th>Customer SKU count</th>
                
                    <th>Competitor name</th>
                
                    <th>Total matches</th>
                
                    <th>Total matches 2 weeks ago</th>
                
                    <th>Matches diff</th>
                
                    <th>Coverage (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Coverage 2 weeks ago (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Coverage diff (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Competitor benchmark coverage (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Benchmark coverage diff (%)</th>
                
                <th>violated</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                
                    <th>Date</th>
                
                    <th>Customer name</th>
                
                    <th>Customer SKU count</th>
                
                    <th>Competitor name</th>
                
                    <th>Total matches</th>
                
                    <th>Total matches 2 weeks ago</th>
                
                    <th>Matches diff</th>
                
                    <th>Coverage (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Coverage 2 weeks ago (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Coverage diff (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Competitor benchmark coverage (%)</th>
                
                    <th>Benchmark coverage diff (%)</th>
                
                <th>violated</th>
    
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
            
                <tr>
                    
                        <td><span>2017-02-20 00:00</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>bestonix (-104)</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>2461</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>target.com (-106)</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>517</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>625</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-108</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>21.0%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>34.4%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-13.4%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>60.0%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-39.0%</span></td>
                    
                    <!-- initialize invisible "violated" column -->
                    <td><span>not</span></td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr>
                    
                        <td><span>2017-02-20 00:00</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>bestonix (-104)</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>2461</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>walmart.com (-105)</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>1052</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>1014</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>38</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>42.7%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>55.7%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-13.0%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>60.0%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-17.3%</span></td>
                    
                    <!-- initialize invisible "violated" column -->
                    <td><span>not</span></td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr>
                    
                        <td><span>2017-02-20 00:00</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>bestonix (-104)</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>2461</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>amazon_bestonix (278)</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>1347</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>1309</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>38</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>54.7%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>72.0%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-17.2%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>60.0%</span></td>
                    
                        <td><span>-5.3%</span></td>
                    
                    <!-- initialize invisible "violated" column -->
                    <td><span>not</span></td>
                </tr>
            
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var BENCHMARK_DIFF_COL = 11;
                var COVERAGE_COL = 7;
                var COVERAGE_DIFF_COL = 9;
                var VIOLATED_COL = 12;
                // Setup column search - add a text input to each footer cell
                $('#matches_table-id tfoot th').each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Filter " style="width:  50px"' + " />");
                });
    
                // DataTable
                var table = $('#matches_table-id').DataTable({
                        //conditional formatting
                        createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
                            if (parseFloat($(data[BENCHMARK_DIFF_COL]).text()) < parseFloat(-20)) {
                                $(row).addClass("red_background");
                                $(row).find('td:eq(' + BENCHMARK_DIFF_COL + ')').addClass("red_bold_font");
                                $(row).find('td:eq(' + VIOLATED_COL + ')').html("<span>violated</span>");
    
    
                            }
                            if (parseFloat($(data[COVERAGE_COL]).text()) < parseFloat(10)) {
                                $(row).addClass("red_background");
                                $(row).find('td:eq(' + COVERAGE_COL + ')').addClass("red_bold_font");
                                $(row).find('td:eq(' + VIOLATED_COL + ')').html("<span>violated</span>");
    
                            }
                            if (parseFloat($(data[COVERAGE_DIFF_COL]).text()) < parseFloat(-15)) {
                                $(row).addClass("red_background");
                                $(row).find('td:eq(' + COVERAGE_DIFF_COL + ')').addClass("red_bold_font");
                                $(row).find('td:eq(' + VIOLATED_COL + ')').html("<span>violated</span>");
    
                            }
                        },
                        //disable ordered column style class change on sorting
                        "orderClasses": false,
    
    
    
    
    
                        dom: 'l Brtip',
                        "aLengthMenu": [
                            [20, 50, 100, -1],
                            [20, 50, 100, "All"]]
    
                    })
                    ;
                // Apply the search
                table.columns().every(function () {
                    var that = this;
    
                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, I am changing the value of the last column according to value in other columns.
The problem: after the values in this column are modified the search is no longer behaves as expected.
it seems that the search behaves like I never changed the values in these cells and sees the previous "default" values from the html table initialization.
I tried to wrap and unwrap the new values with `<span>` tag but with no success to solve the problem.
What am I missing out here?

Comment: Did you try to move your event input code to drawCallback ?

Comment: can you explain what would that accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use API methods such as [`cell().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) to modify cell content after the table has been initialized.

For example:

```
this.api().cell(row, VIOLATED_COL).data('<span>violated</span>');
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xtesc62b/) for code and demonstration.

Generally, it's better to use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to produce a content for a cell but in your case it makes sense to keep the logic together in one place.